# Using a generic (X) delegate in a generic (Y) method where Y extends some base class. Cannot convert to base class

Tags: c#, class, generics, constraints

```
public abstract class SomeBaseClass {}

public class SomeSpecificClass: SomeBaseClass {
    public int propertyA;
    public string propertyB;
}

public delegate void Callback<T>(T data);


public class Foo {


    void MethodA <T> (Callback<T> theInstance) where T: SomeBaseClass {
        MethodB(theInstance);
    }

    void MethodB(Callback<SomeBaseClass> theInstance) {

    }

    void MethodC() {
        Callback<SomeSpecificClass> cb = (data) => {};
        MethodA(cb);
    }

    void MethodD <T> (T theInstance) where T: SomeBaseClass {
        MethodE(theInstance);
    }

    void MethodE (SomeBaseClass theInstance) {

    }
}
```

Produces the error in `MethodA`:

`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Callback<T>' to 'Callback<SomeBaseClass>' [Assembly-CSharp]
Callback<T> theInstance`

But MethodD works fine passing its instance to MethodE

Why can't I pass the generic `Callback<T>` instance in MethodA to argument of type `Callback<SomeBaseClass>` in MethodB when I'm specifiying the constraint that T extends SomeBaseClass

Comment: Because `theInstance` can be written to access, say `propertyA` and yet `MethodB` might attempt to call it passing an instance of some *other* type derived by `SomeBaseClass` that doesn't even have a `propertyA`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have updated code example, why is it fine for MethodD to pass its instance to MethodE, but when wrapped in a generic delegate it errors when it's in a similar style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you can't do this because it's not safe.

Suppose we have a concrete class derived from `SomeBaseClass`:

```
public class SomeOtherSpecificClass {}
```

Suppose we change your `MethodB` to:

```
void MethodB(Callback<SomeBaseClass> theInstance)
{
    theInstance(new SomeOtherSpecificClass());
}
```

That should compile, right? After all, you're just passing a `SomeOtherSpecificClass` into a `Callback<SomeBaseClass>`, which should be fine.

Then if I call `MethodA` like this:

```
Callback<SomeSpecificClass> callbcak = data => Console.WriteLine(data.propertyA);
MethodA(callback);
```

... then if all of that were allowed, we'd be passing a `SomeOtherSpecificClass` into a delegate expecting a `SomeSpecificClass`.

Your `MethodD` and `MethodE` examples are fine, because `MethodE` can only use members of `SomeBaseClass`... but a `Callback<SomeSpecificClass>` really *requires* a `SomeSpecificClass`, so you can't just treat it as if it were a method accepting a `SomebaseClass`.

To show this more simply:

```
// This is valid...
string text = "";
object obj = text;

// This isn't...
Action<string> stringAction = text => Console.WriteLine(text.Length);
Action<object> objectAction = stringAction;
// ... because it would allow this:
objectAction(new object());
```

Comment: Ahh yes I see. Hmm back to the drawing board I suppose

Answer (score 3):

It is not allowed, because you want to perform illegal assigning. If it will be allowed, that mean you can pass  as argument instance of base class to method, that actual needs instance of inherited class:

```
Action<TChild> source;
Action<TBase> target;

//your intention:
target = source;
//will be compiled, but as it actual "source", that needs childInstance, not baseInstance,
//it is illegal
target(baseInstance);
```

You can try to fix it or clearly understand via contravariance(**in** keyword):

```
public delegate void Callback<in T>(T data);

void MethodA(Callback<SomeBaseClass> theInstance)
{
    MethodB(theInstance);
}

void MethodB<T>(Callback<T> theInstance) where T : SomeBaseClass
{
}
```

**Legal usage:**

```
Action<TBase> source;
Action<TChild> target;

//your intention:
target = source;
//will work, because it is actual "source", that needs TBase or inherited types like TChild
target(childInstance);
```